# Selecting Transparent Areas Within A Selection In Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I am trying to make a quick selection of a line art drawing which is all in black and that is on a layer which has transparent areas within the drawing itself. Of course any of the quick selection methods will also deselect the transparent areas within the drawing. I am basically just trying to end up with an outline/selection/path running around the edge of the line art drawing that includes the transparent area within the selection as well so that I can fill all the transparent areas with black. If I make a selection of the object and then reverse the selection then the problem is it also selects the areas outside of the object as well. So that wont work. I assume there must be a faster way to do what I am trying to do than by using the pen tool to try to create a path by hand around the edges of the drawing?

Thank you kindly for any help you might be able to offer on this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a screenshot of the work and layers. As it stands this question is too broad to give you a meaningful answer as we have no idea how fine the lines are, how detailed the drawing is, etc..

Answer (score 1):

I guess your drawing is a bitmap, vectors can have more ideal ways. This is for bitmaps.

Select the emptiness around the object with the magic wand, set option "Contiguous" ON before selecting. Isolated transparent areas stay unselected.

If you just want to select the isolated empty areas inside your drawing, keep Contiguous=OFF and select the emptiness. Then turn Contiguous=ON, Alt+Click with the magic wand the unwanted emptiness outside the shape.

NOT ASKED: In Photoshop there's by default anti-aliasing=ON, you may have one pixel wide fuzzy areas around your black areas. If you are going to use the Paint Bucket to fill the selected empty areas, it will generate another one pix wide fuzzy zone around the fill, so you have total 2 pix wide fuzzy zone between Black and Color like this:

[image]

My recommendation: Select the outside emptiness only, expand the selection 1...2 px, invert the selection and fill the selected area to a new layer below your drawing.

You get this:

[image]

Merge the layers after you are 200% sure they are ready, not before.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, there is one black color with a stroke at 100% and a fill with some transparency.

The Magic Wand only detect colors but not the opacity.

I think you’re looking for this:

- Go to the Channels Panel.
- Duplicate one channel.
- The channels only have black values, no transparency.

Now you can use the Magic Wand Tool to select just the black color.

See the images below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your replies. In the end I figured it out. I clicked on the background of the line art image with the magic wand tool and then inverted the selection. That gave me the the selection around the edges of the drawing that I needed. Thanks again.